# How to use for loop in fortran

Tags: for-loop, fortran

My professor told me something interesting during the class today.
professor said "if you use the preprocessor, you can use for loop in fortran".
but I know that fortran not support the for loop.
I think I can use it in that format,I don't know how it works.

Comment: Have you googled 'for loop fortran'?

Comment: I know that fortran not support the for loop. but maybe using macro?.. you can use it in for loop format.

Comment: explain why you think you need one

Comment: If your professor is seriously suggesting you use a preprocessor to translate  something like `for (i=1;i<25;i++)` into `do i = 1,24` then your professor is an idiot.  It might be an interesting classroom exercise, but don't let the idea out into the wild.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop is in Fortran is called the DO loop, but it is the same. You can call any loop that uses an integer (or integral) counter and counts in specific steps *a for loop* no matter which keyword is actually used in the language.

The do loop in Fortran IS *a for loop*:

```
    do i = 1, 10, 2
      do something with i
    end do
```

can be called a for loop without any problem. The `for` keyword was invented after the invention of Fortran.

Some languages, like C, have more general for loops, but that does not matter here.